# REST/JSON : How to generate sample requests ? How to expose API?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, wsdl

Using java, when I expose some web service with Soap, I have a WSDL which describes all input/output, and if I use this WSDL in my SoapUI client, it will analyze it and generate some sample request for me.

What is the process to do this with Rest/Json. I know about wadl, but SoapUI can't generate sample request from this. I know about third party tools like Swagger suite, but is this the only way ? Do u have to use some external documentation tool to expose your API and show users some sample requests ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Well, swagger is now a "standard" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_Specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no answer yet, so here is one a few years later.

You need to use [OpenAPI Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/) (let's call the result a "Swagger contract"), which defines a standard, language-agnostic interface to RESTful APIs and just forget about WADL.

This will be the equivalent of a SOAP WSDL, but easier to read , easier to produce, and lighter in constraints.

With Swagger, you can work in "Contract first" (using https://editor.swagger.io/ to design the contract) or in "Code first", where you will use frameworks like [Springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) to generate the swagger contract from code + annotations. The last one is much easier imo, and it's just a different way of doing "contract first", it's not like if u were implementing the whole application before designing the contract.

Once you have the "swagger contract" document available on an URL, you can deploy a swagger-ui website to visualize it in an interactive way : it will generate some sample requests and will allow you to execute these requests after customizing them.

Answer (score -1):

```
 try {
           url="put your service url";
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                // Build JSON string
                JSONStringer item = new JSONStringer()
                        .object()
                        .key("password").value(pass)
                        .key("username").value(email)
                        .endObject();
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(item.toString());

                request.setEntity(entity);

                // Send request to WCF service
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity1.getContent();
                r = Splash.convertStreamToString(stream);
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(r);
                s=  (Integer) jo.get("Flag");
                Log.d("json result is:", r);
            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            Log.d("error", "code"+0);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Anything you've written is related to my question ?